# Appjs run function after node.js function has ran

Tags: javascript, node.js, appjs

I am trying to make a simple read file function in my Appjs program. All that is happening is that the Appjs is calling a function inside my `app.js` file and running it in node.js. This function then returns a value to my Appjs program by `window.returnData = data;`

This works, however I can't get it to work in the order I want. The node.js function seems to be running AFTER the Appjs function although it is inside of it.

Here is the function inside of my Appjs `index.html` file that starts the entire process.

```
var returnData;
function r(path,d) {
    window.readFromFile(path,d); //call to the function readFromFile below
    alert(returnData);
}
```

`readFromFile()` function from the app.js file that Is being called from above

```
window.readFromFile = function(path,d) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    if (d == 1) {
        path = __dirname + path;
    }
    fs.readFile(path, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err,data){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('File read');
            window.returnData = data;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my problem. The first call of this function will alert the text `undefined`. However, after the alert function, I know that the `window.returnData = data;` line above is working because if I create a button to alert the variable `returnData` again or I run the `readFromFile` function again, it alerts the data correctly.

Am I incorrect in thinking that the child function should complete first? Is there a way around this? I don't want to create a loop that continuously checks for the variable to change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Am I incorrect in thinking that the child function should complete first"* Absolutely. readFile is asynchronous.

Comment: @KevinB ah, I didn't know that. I guess I should've read up on that function since node.js even says that it "Asynchronously reads the entire contents of a file. " in the documentation. Is there a way to make my function wait for the data to be read into the variable?

Comment: @KevinB I feel pretty dumb. Hours of coding just has my mind blank. I have the `window.returnData = data;` now as a callback to a function instead that has the alert(data) in it.

Comment: Exactly, just use the callback as it is intended. readFromFile should accept a callback, and execute said callback upon completion.